# How to plot following exponential function properly

Tags: r, statistics, curve-fitting, exponential, non-linear-regression

Data

```
|   x       |   Y       |
|   --------|   --------|
|   26.88   |   3.16    |
|   28.57   |   4.21    |
|   30.94   |   2.97    |
|   33.90   |   3.06    |
|   37.24   |   2.87    |
|   39.76   |   2.95    |
|   41.89   |   2.70    |
|   44.37   |   1.25    |
|   27.20   |   5.04    |
|   26.54   |   6.69    |
|   29.21   |   4.42    |
|   33.26   |   3.15    |
|   34.80   |   3.20    |
|   37.87   |   3.11    |
|   41.88   |   2.95    |
|   44.13   |   2.26    |
|   26.42   |   7.07    |
|   24.02   |   8.72    |
|   29.73   |   6.38    |
|   31.10   |   3.85    |
|   33.16   |   3.00    |
|   36.76   |   3.28    |
|   43.26   |   3.18    |
|   42.06   |   2.73    |
|   26.73   |   9.44    |
|   23.03   |   9.72    |
|   27.07   |   6.98    |
|   29.04   |   4.67    |
|   31.83   |   3.55    |
|   36.29   |   3.89    |
|   39.45   |   3.55    |
|   42.17   |   3.37    |
|   23.51   |   10.44   |
|   21.98   |   10.90   |
|   27.21   |   8.13    |
|   28.63   |   5.76    |
|   30.92   |   3.96    |
|   35.57   |   3.94    |
|   38.33   |   3.88    |
|   40.91   |   3.58    |
|   25.15   |   13.05   |
|   19.44   |   15.91   |
|   25.94   |   10.37   |
|   28.03   |   5.17    |
|   31.25   |   4.04    |
|   35.31   |   4.24    |
|   37.02   |   4.31    |
|   38.89   |   3.99    |
|   25.12   |   15.66   |
|   18.36   |   19.86   |
|   25.05   |   12.82   |
|   27.58   |   6.07    |
|   28.83   |   4.11    |
|   33.76   |   4.17    |
|   34.48   |   4.30    |
|   37.32   |   3.97    |
|   21.27   |   20.49   |
|   16.61   |   25.53   |
|   22.68   |   16.58   |
|   25.63   |   6.34    |
|   28.15   |   4.40    |
|   32.80   |   3.99    |
|   35.27   |   4.59    |
|   36.75   |   4.35    |
```

Code

```
library(data.table)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggpmisc)
setwd("E:/")
Data_2 <- read_excel("Data_2.xlsx")

model.0 <- lm(log(Strength) ~ Theoritical, data= Data_2)  
alpha.0 <- exp(coef(model.0)[1])
beta.0 <- coef(model.0)[2]

# Starting parameters
start <- list(alpha = alpha.0, beta = beta.0)
start

model <- nls(Strength ~ alpha * exp((1/beta) * Theoritical) , data = Data_2, start = start)
summary(model)
# Plot fitted curve
plot(Data_2$Theoritical, Data_2$Strength)
line(Data_2$Theoritical, predict(model, list(x = Data_2$Theoritical)), col = 'skyblue')
```

When draw my plot I got following image.

[image]

I need this kind of equation for my data
y=a*e^(-x/b)

[image]

I could not get the R^2 value as well as shown in this picture

[image]

Please correct my code as well. kindly help me to provide a good code for this best fit graph for that equation. I am new to R programming.

Comment: Please rpvodide the question in minimal reproducible form.  The data should be shown as the output of dput and the column names should correspond to the code in the question.     Do not include library statements for packages that are not used and do not include code such as `setwd` and `read_excel` that can't run without your specific setup.  Please read the the too of the [tag:r] tag page for info on asking questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.